# How to Django remote access to server using Windows

Tags: python, django, windows, server

I'm starting the [tango-with-django](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/setup.html) tutorial.
And I'm trying to access the created website using other computer. Both computers are using Windows OS. And this is not working.

```
$ python manage.py runserver <your_machines_ip_address>:5555
```

I'm using the IPv4 Adress that I get when I type:

```
$ ipconfig
```

What am I doing wrong or what is missing?

Comment: Does the `runserver` command not work or you cannot access the other machine? Is this over LAN? Any firewall restrictions?

Comment: @kedar, the `runserver` command works. And I'm trying to access using a computer outside the LAN. I desactivated the firewall in my windows. Does it maybe has to do with the router?

Comment: Yes, a (good) router will block everything by default (unless you set up port-forwards / DMZ).  See my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Download `ngrok` from here: https://ngrok.com/ (this will allow you to serve your web app to anyone on the Internet)

Start your Django project normally or provide any port number.

`python manage.py runserver`

If you are running windows, open a command prompt and browse to the location where the ngrok binary is located.
If you are running GNU/Linux / OSX, just open a terminal.

Then run the following command.

`ngrok 8000`

Replace `8000` by whichever port the Django project is running on.

`ngrok` will give you a public hostname like `http://abc.ngrok.com`

Anyone you give this address to will be able to view / interact with your Django application anywhere on the Internet.

---

**Update**: Newer versions of `ngrok` need to be run like this: `ngrok http 8000`

Comment: Keday, thank you it worked with ngrok. Is there any draback to use ngrok and not changing the router configurations?

Comment: This is only meant for development or testing purposes. If you want to deploy something for real, consider using a VPS / SaaS application to host your Django project. (See DigitalOcean / Linode / EC2 / Heroku)

Comment: thank you for the help! Just one more question, do you know from where does ngrok creates an IP Adress for my project? Does it search for not used IP adresses?

Comment: I'm not sure about the specifics but ngrok creates / allocates a subdomain (which is the `abc` part of `abc.ngrok.com`) on ngrok.com and tunnels all traffic on that subdomain to and from your computer. It doesn't give you a special IP address.

Answer (score -1):

Try `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:5555`. And access it on the other machine using `http://<your-ip-address>:5555`. That should work